# Ruby on rails How do I display data associated with a specific row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, relationship

In my ruby on rails application I have a show.html.erb page that displays the details of a film, what I want to do is display the dates that film is being shown. In the show.html.erb file I have done this so far:

```
<% @film.showings.each do |film| %>
    <%= @film.showings.show_date %>         
<% end %>
```

And in my models I have the associations:

film.rb:

```
class Film < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :showings
    validates :title, presence: true,  length: { minimum: 3 }
end
```

showing.rb:

```
class Showing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :film
end
```

In my showings_controller.rb:

```
class ShowingsController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @showing = Showing.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

What am I doing wrong? At the minute I get the error:

NoMethodError in Films#show 
undefined method `show_date` for #

What should I be doing?

Comment: Doing that displays the error: undefined method `showings' for #<Showing:0x5b596c0>

Comment: Which controller does `show.html.erb` belong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that's the problem, but the code in `show.html.erb` is wrong. You are looping over `@film`'s showing, but INSIDE the loop you're stil referring to ALL the showings (`@film.showings`). Inside, try this:

```
<% @film.showings.each do |showing| %>
    <%= showing.show_date %>         
<% end %>
```